# Why is binary data posted to flask app different?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm posting binary data (a pdf file, for example) to a flask app.  I expect the data received by the server to match the data I'm posting, but it doesn't.  I'm guessing it might be encoding related, but I'm not sure where to go.

**edit**:
The client is running on MacOS Mojave, the server is running in AWS Lambda

The client code looks like this:

```py
import requests
import os

data = None
with open("infile.pdf", "rb") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
print("length of input data: {}".format(len(data)))
print("first 40: {}".format(data[:40]))

the_url = os.environ['BASE_DOMAIN'] + "/binary"
res = requests.post(url=the_url,
                    data=data,
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

the output looks like this:

```
12:14 $ python tester.py
length of input data: 1728914
first 40: b'%PDF-1.5\n%\xe4\xf0\xed\xf8\n4 0 obj\n<</Type/XObject/S'
```

The server code looks like this:

```py
@app.route("/binary", methods=["POST"])
def create_binary():
    print(request.content_type)
    if request.content_type == "application/octet-stream":
        print("content length header: {}".format(request.content_length))
        data = request.get_data()
        print("length of input data: {}".format(len(data)))
        print("first 40: {}".format(data[:40]))

        return jsonify({
            'msg': "success"
        })
    else:
        return jsonify({
            'msg': "415 Unsupported Media Type ;)"
        })
```

and its output looks like this:

```
application/octet-stream
content length header: 3118403
length of input data: 3118403
first 40: b'%PDF-1.5\n%\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\n4 0 obj\n<</Type/X'
```

Comment: maybe you should use `request.post(..., files=...)` - [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: your code works correctly on my computer. Linux Mint 19.2, Python 3.7.4, Flask 1.0.3, requests 2.22.0

Comment: i left out an important piece, @furas, the server code is running on a different machine, specifically lambda in AWS, which leads me to believe more that it is encoding of some sort.  i'll edit my question.

Comment: I took your code and deployed to lamba (with small changes) and it works correctly. Client works on Linux Mint so the only idea is that requests on MacOS decode bytes to string before sending to server. In my code I also created version which use `request.post(..., files=...)` similar to form on web pages so maybe it will work correctly. Code for server and client on github [flask/lambda-zappa-upload-file](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/lambda-zappa-upload-file)

Comment: I deployed your code as is and it worked correctly, so obviously it is something weird.  I'm deploying via serverless as opposed to zappa, so there may be something in there, too.  Later today or maybe tomorrow I'm going to deploy mine via zappa, see what happens.  I'll get to the bottom of this.  If you want to write a true answer out of the code you posted, I'll mark it as such.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact issue. If you are using lambda proxy in API Gateway then the binary data is being encoded that's the problem, you need to make the binary data [passthrough](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html). If you are using awsgi for using flask. Then you will need to map the events(from lambda to lambda proxy) too. I am not sure if there is any library that does this mapping.